# How many solutions are there in equation $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}=15\space, \space x_1\geq 1\space ,\space 0\leq x_i\leq9$ for $i=1$ to $10$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

### Question

> How many solutions are there in equation  $$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}=15\space, \space x_1\geq 1\space ,\space 0\leq x_i\leq9$$ for $i=1$ to $10$

### My Approach

$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}=15\space, \space x_1\geq 1\space ,\space 0\leq x_i\leq9$$

Let us find the restriction for $x_{1}\geq 1$

Let $x_{1}=x_{1}^{'}+1$

So our solution boils down to

$$x_1^{'}+1+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}=15\space$$

$$x_1^{'}+x_2+\cdots+x_{10}=14\space$$

> Number of Solution =$$\binom{10+14-1}{14}=\binom{23}{14}$$

Among  $$\binom{23}{5},$$ we have to subtract the restriction for $0 \leq x_{i} \leq 9$

if we take $i=2$,i.e  $0 \leq x_{i} \leq 9$

i.e Subtract $$x_{2}\geq10$$ from $$\binom{23}{5},$$

calculating for restriction $$x_{2}\geq10$$ using the above approach,

we get

$$x_1+x_2^{'}+\cdots+x_{10}=5\space$$

=$$\binom{10+5-1}{5}=\binom{14}{5}$$

We will find the restriction for every $i=1$ to $10$ and then subtract it from

$$\binom{23}{5},$$

Hence required number of solution=$$\binom{23}{5}-10*\binom{14}{5}$$

But the answer says that it is

$${{23}\choose{9}} - {{14}\choose{9}} - 9{{13}\choose{9}}$$

I am confused.Please help me out where i am getting wrong ??

Comment: Your question is confusing $x1\geq 1$ and also $x1\geq 0$ so can $x1$ be $0$?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar With over 10k reputation and more than $700$ answers, you should, in my opinion, be able to use underscores for indices. Even in comments.

Comment: Okay thanks will follow from next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_{10}=15$, $x_1\ge1$, $x_i\ge 0$ is equal to the number of solutions for $(x_1-1)+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_{10}=14$, $x_1-1\ge 0$, $x_i\ge 0$, i.e.

$$\binom{14+9}{9}=\binom{23}{9}$$

The number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_{10}=15$, $x_1> 9$, $x_i\ge 0$ is equal to the number of solutions for $(x_1-10)+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_{10}=5$, $x_1-10\ge 0$, $x_i\ge 0$, i.e.

$$\binom{5+9}{9}=\binom{14}{9}$$

For $j=2,3,\dots, 10$, the number of solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+x_{10}=15$, $x_1\ge 1$, $x_j>9$, $x_i\ge 0$ (if $i\ne j$) is equal to the number of solutions for $(x_1-1)+x_2+\cdots+(x_j-10)+\cdots+x_{10}=4$, $x_1-1\ge0$, $x_j-10\ge 0$, $x_i\ge 0$  (if $i\ne j$), i.e.

$$\binom{4+9}{9}=\binom{13}{9}$$

Since it is impossible that $x_j>9$ and $x_k>9$ for two different $j$ and $k$, the number of solution is

$$\binom{23}{9}-\binom{14}{9}-9\binom{13}{9}$$

Comment: Alright !the problem in my approach is that i have not taken seperate case for $x_{1}\geq 1$ and  $x_{1}\geq 9$. Isn't it?

Comment: @laura I think so.